# Here map does not display after update to latest SDK 3.2.2

Tags: android, here-api

I've updated our app to use the latest version of Here Map SDK for Android (3.2.2_152).

The reason to update Here SDK to bypass OpenSSL issue from Google Play.

Now the map does not display (it worked with v3.1.1).

I tried to create a new project to follow the latest guide but it is not displayed either.

Is anyone facing this issue?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a stack trace? (e.g. pause the debugger when you are seeing this issue and provide stack). Also, you can check if anything interesting is displayed in Logcat.

Comment: @AndrewJC detailed about our issue is: After we call MapEngine.getInstance().init(), it hang the main thread and do not jump into onEngineInitializationCompleted of OnEngineInitListener callback(older sdk works normally). It did not crash for stack-trace provided. But dive deep, I found this issue is only from our old app. With new application (which created last week, it work. But app was created Dec 2015, it doesn't)
Could you provide us some advices on this situation? If you are from Here, and need the detail info of our app, pls contact me via email hieu.truong@fruitful.io.
Many thanks

Comment: Both AndrewJC and I work for HERE. This issue has been logged and fixed  in our main line. Can you please post a code snippet of how your app initializes the engine? We are interested to know how this regression was introduced and not caught. The current work around is to use MapEngine#init() before loading the view fragments. However the workaround may depend on how you have structured the initialization code.

Really sorry about the regression and any inconvenience.

Comment: @DavidLeong you're right.

My old code, I call MapEngine#init() on Fragment#onActivityCreated and it hangs my application.
So after I call MapEngine#init before Activity#setOnCreateView and it works.
Unfortunately, if I turn off network connection and everything seems back to the beginning(App is not responding). So do you have any workaround about this. I try same case with our new app and It works normally.

Comment: No, I will need to investigate and get back to you. Can you please provide more information? What is the call stack ?

Comment: Here is my code snippet. 
HereActivity http://pastebin.com/QATz046X.
HereFragment http://pastebin.com/DYNEAtka.
My first idea is: on Fragment that use HereMap, we call Here initialized. As you know with old app registered, after call HereActivity#initializeHere() it hangs the main thread. With your workaround, I call HereActivity#initializeHere() on very first activity create and it works if network is available. If I disconnect the network It still hangs my app. If have any chance to workaround or a update sdk, pls let me know. Thank for your support.

Comment: @DavidLeong could you pls tell me about when will the next fixed SDK? I need to update our app ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update should already be live. Please check the developer portal.